# mysql: retrieve one distinct id for all duplicate user entries instead of all id where duplication occured

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, heidisql

I want retrieve one  distinct id  for all duplicate user emails instead of all id where duplication occured.

I have a table of users. This table has an ID and an Email. in the table the ID is unique however the email is not unique. there are duplicate emails.

I want return an ID of each duplicate entry of email. I do not want to return all the ID of duplicate emails. If there 2 IDs from one duplicate entry I want to return 1 of them.

| ID | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@go.co |
| ----- | ------------- |
| 2 | e_m@go.co |
| ----- | ------------- |
| 3 | email1@go.co |
| ----- | ------------- |
| 4 | mail2@go.co |
| ---- | ------------ |
| 4 | e_m@go.co |
| ---- | ------------ |

In this case I want to return **1 or 3** for **email1@go.co** not both, and **2 or 4** for **e_m@go.co**.
I have tried  some thing like this but this is not working.

`SELECT id FROM (SELECT distinct(email), id from users where email = email);`

I am therefore to look for support. does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

**NOTE:**

normally it is possible to get duplicate by using the count(email) >1. However this will return all the duplicates information, and this not what I want. I only want one value for each duplicated value so 1 out of 2 possible values.
So that is why I am using Distinct on **email**. However I interested in **ID** of the distinct email, not directly in the **email**. This **ID** is what I want to use later. So that is why I did a `select distinct(email), ID from users;` because I want to also have the ID of the **distinct email**. Then select the **ID** of the returned select results. However the problem is that this syntactically not correct.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Because this looks very different if you're using a pre-8.0 version.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am using mysql  Version 8.1.0

Comment: I have edited the question to bring more light to the problem. I hope this will be reopened because it is not a duplicate to any of the suggested 34 questions

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate? If you get the row with the highest ID grouped by email, isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: `SELECT email, MAX(id) FROM users GROUP BY email`

Comment: FYI, `DISTINCT(email)` doesn't do what you think it does. `DISTINCT` applies to the entire SELECT list, not a single column. It's not a function.